# How do I have my custom toolbar have its items updated via IElementUpdater

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I've implemented a custom toolbar in my RCP application.  I'm also using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension to contribute commands to the custom toolbar.

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution            
       locationURI="toolbar:com.my.custom.toolbar.identifier.toolbar">
     <command
           commandId="com.my.command.id"
           icon="icons/my_icon.png"
           style="toggle"
           tooltip="My Toggle Tooltip">
      </command>
   </menuContribution>
 </extension>
```

I've written the code that finds these IConfigurationElements and turns them into CommandContributionItems which I use to add them to my custom toolbar.

I have some toolbar items that are of type toggle, and I need these to update their UI using the `IElementUpdater` interface that the command's handler implements.

I also contribute this command to a standard Eclipse menu... like "toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar"  and its toggle state is updated via the IElementUpdater when appropriate.

I'm probably missing something in my custom toolbar that hooks it up to the IElementUpdater, but I have no idea where to start looking to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the IElementUpdater, but not for cases to update the toggle state, as this should be done by the connection to the respective Command. There exist, however, some problems in Eclipse 4 which I have already started to point out in a [blog article](http://www.descher.at/descher-vu/2013/02/synchronising-stateful-items-part1/).

What Eclipse variant are you using? 3.x or 4.x? There exists a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398647) in 4.x concerning the synchronization of contributions and their command states.

Comment: I'm running a 3.x RCP application.  It's made up of a CoolBar with CoolItems which contain the ToolBars.

Comment: Well in that case, if you are trying to solve the toggle problem only, take a look at this article http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/03/commands-part-6-toggle-radio-menu.html .. the toggling is solve using a connection to a command and its respectiv command state.

Comment: I've seen that article you've linked to, and I've successfully used the samples in it to get the updating of the toggle buttons on the main Eclipse toolbar.  It's my custom toolbar that's not working.  I think I need to dedicate some time to read through Eclipse source code to see how Eclipse's main tool bar is getting the notification from the IElementUpdater.

Comment: A teammate of mine figured out that we had a threading issue.  (It's a long story, and I have a limited number of characters to use here).  I'll count this as a correct answer since it addresses the issue that most other people might have.